# Javascript not working with jquery library 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, javascript-framework

I'm struggling trying to get this to work an be compatible with one of the later versions of the jquery library.  Before I was using the version 1.3.2, but would like to update that version to 1.9.1 for the time being.  I ran some tests and found out there is a few sections of javascript that also need to be updated but can't seem to figure it out - so I'm handing this over to you all - could you please help me figure this out?

**EDIT:**
I have two out of three main areas that are giving me troubles...I'll provide them below with where I think the issue may be... one of the parts have been solved but am still struggling with these two parts below.

JAVASCRIPT - Part 1

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.rate_widget').each(function (i) {
        var widget = this;
        var out_data = {
            widget_id: $(widget).attr('id'),
            fetch: 1
        };
        $.post(
            '--Ratings/ratings.php',
        out_data,

        function (INFO) {
            $(widget).data('fsr', INFO);
            set_votes(widget);
        },
            'json');
    });

    $('.ratings_stars').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
        set_votes($(this).parent());
    });

    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function () {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();

        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on: $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id: $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
            '--Ratings/ratings.php',
        clicked_data,

        function (INFO) {
            widget.data('fsr', INFO);
            set_votes(widget);
        },
            'json');
    });

});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes); /* ===== <-- Here ===== */

    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text(votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)');
}
```

JAVASCRIPT - Part 2

```
$(function () {
    $('input.field').focus(function () {
        if (this.title == this.value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    })
        .blur(function () {
        if (this.value == '') { /* ===== <-- Here ===== */
            this.value = this.title;
        }
    });
    var currentPage = 1;
    $('#slider_profile .buttons_profile span').live('click', function () {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("img").trigger("slidermove") /* ===== <-- Here ===== */
        }, 100);

        var fragments_count = $(this).parents('#slider_profile:eq(0)').find('.fragment_profile').length;
        var fragment_width = $(this).parents('#slider_profile:eq(0)').find('.fragment_profile').width();
        var perPage = 1;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(fragments_count / perPage);
        var stepMove = fragment_width * perPage;
        var container = $(this).parents('#slider_profile:eq(0)').find('.con_profile');
        var firstPosition = 0;
        var lastPosition = -((numPages - 1) * stepMove);
        if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
            currentPage++;
            if (currentPage > numPages) {
                currentPage = 1;
                container.animate({
                    'left': firstPosition
                });
                return;
            }; /* ===== <-- Here ===== */
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }; /* ===== <-- Here ===== */

        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
            currentPage--;
            if (currentPage < 1) {
                currentPage = numPages;
                container.animate({
                    'left': lastPosition
                });
                return;
            }; /* ===== <-- Here ===== */
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }; /* ===== <-- Here ===== */
    });
});
```

I could also be completely wrong in the locations where I marked ( <-- Here ) next to where I believe is the problems that need to be fixed.  So with all that in mind, could someone help me figure out how to make these parts work with one of the latest versions of jquery 1.9.1 ?

Comment: change this: `$(a.attr('href'));` to `$(a).attr('href');`

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Comment: Some of the features you're using (such as `live`) are deprecated and have been removed.

Comment: I'm quite sure you have some error messages in console...

Comment: Well, props for at least attempting to upgrade from such an old version

Comment: @j08691, As the migrate is for 1.9 versions and later - I think that only would work if using no later than version 1.6.4... I however am upgrading from version 1.3.2.  I'd like to not have to worry about the migrate all in it's entirety if possible and simply upgrade to 1.9.1 while updating my current javascript to suit that version.

Comment: No, you need it. Add it, see what errors it gives you, fix them, then remove migrate.

Comment: could you check this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/wR2pZ/3/  If you click on the 'jshints', red dots appear - This is actually how I was able to see any errors (if accurate) -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIRST, try this

JAVASCRIPT - Part 1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.head').click(function () {
        var a = $(this);
        var section = a.attr('href');
        section.removeClass('section');
        $('.section').hide();
        section.addClass('section');
        if (section.is(':visible')) {
            section.slideToggle(); /* ===== <-- 400 is the default duration ===== */
        } else {
            section.slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

JAVASCRIPT - PART 2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rate_widget').each(function () {
        var widget = $(this);
        var out_data = {
            widget_id: widget.attr('id'),
            fetch: 1
        };
        $.post(
            '--Ratings/ratings.php',
        out_data,

        function (INFO) {
            widget.data('fsr', INFO);
            set_votes(widget);
        },
            'json');
    });

    $('.ratings_stars').hover(function () {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
    }, function () {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
        set_votes($(this).parent());
    });

    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function () {
        var star = $(this);
        var widget = star.parent();
        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on: star.attr('class'),
            widget_id: star.parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
            '--Ratings/ratings.php',
        clicked_data,

        function (INFO) {
            widget.data('fsr', INFO);
            set_votes(widget);
        },
            'json');
    });

});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = widget.data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = widget.data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = widget.data('fsr').dec_avg;

    console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + widget.data('fsr').number_votes);

    widget.find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    widget.find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
    widget.find('.total_votes').text(votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)');
}
```

JAVASCRIPT - PART 3

```
$(function () {
    $('input.field').focus(function () {
        if (this.title == this.value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        if (this.value === '') { /* ===== <-- Here ===== */
            this.value = this.title;
        }
    });
    var currentPage = 1;
    $(document).on('click', $('#slider_profile .buttons_profile span'), function () {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("img").trigger("slidermove"); /* ===== <-- Here ===== */
        }, 100);

        var fragments_count = $(this).parents('#slider_profile:eq(0)').find('.fragment_profile').length;
        var fragment_width = $(this).parents('#slider_profile:eq(0)').find('.fragment_profile').width();
        var perPage = 1;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(fragments_count / perPage);
        var stepMove = fragment_width * perPage;
        var container = $(this).parents('#slider_profile:eq(0)').find('.con_profile');
        var firstPosition = 0;
        var lastPosition = -((numPages - 1) * stepMove);
        if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
            currentPage++;
            if (currentPage > numPages) {
                currentPage = 1;
                container.animate({
                    'left': firstPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
            currentPage--;
            if (currentPage < 1) {
                currentPage = numPages;
                container.animate({
                    'left': lastPosition
                });
                return;
            }
            container.animate({
                'left': -((currentPage - 1) * stepMove)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm still running into the same issue - where I have marked /* ===== <-- Here ===== */ is where I believe my issue is... Also, not sure how accurate jsfiddle is for seeing where errors are, but here is a jsfiddle of just the javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/wR2pZ/3/  If you click on the jshints, you see red dots where there is a problem...How would I fix that?

Comment: That part works ;) -- Thank you, could you possibly help with the other 2 parts?

Comment: Did it, but i'm not sure of the JQuery $.post method as i don't use it. And the :eq() selector as well.

Comment: Let me give this a try and I'll quickly get back to you!

Comment: I just changed deprecated .live() method to .on() Good luck.

Comment: You my friend are a life-savor!  Thank you very much for all your help - There was only 1 minor change I had to do from what you provided but with that said, everything is now updated and working perfectly on 1.9.1 --> On the first part, the only minor change I added was this: `var section = $(a.attr('href'));` without the $(), it wasn't working properly - in case you were wondering, other than that small minor change, everything else works like a charm!  So again, a BIG Thank you!